# Unable to import namespace in different project but within the same solution in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a solution whose structure is similar to:

[image]

I am trying to import the `TypeConverters` namespace into `MainWindow`'s static resources so that I can use `MyTypeConverter` in a binding.

After doing some reading I know that I have to add the assembly if importing a namespace that is not within the same assembly.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:TypeConverters;assembly=ClassLibrary1"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <converters:MyTypeConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Visual Studio tells me that "The name MyTypeConverter does not exist in the namespace clr-namespace:TypeConverters;assembly=ClassLibrary1"

Not quite sure what to do here. Am I referencing this correctly? Do I need to use different syntax since it exists in the same solution?

Thanks

Comment: The xaml-code is only half of the rent, your "WpfApp1" must have a reference to "ClassLibrary1". open references on wpfapp, rightlick on it -> "add reference" -> projects -> select classlibrary1

Comment: also the frameworks of the projects must be compatible

Comment: You need to compile the class library.